# Missing Schemas in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

A little bit of an odd issue here.

I have a database, hosted on SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2), that has 10 different schemas that could be used for reporting purposes:

[image: SQL Server Schema List]

Please note, for company compliance reasons, I did redact this image to the bare essentials.

Now, when I go to create a report, and connect to the database in question, the only schemas that are presented to me are those starting with lm_:

[image: Crystal Schema List]

Again, redacted...

Now, for the purpose of the report I need to build, I need to be able to select against tables that are in one of the ls_ schemas.

My question is, in Crystal Reports 2013, **how do I make all available schemas visible for use in a report?**

Other important things to note:

1. I am able to log into SSMS as the same account I am using to connect to the database in Crystal Reports, and am able to successfully run queries against the schemas in question.
2. The account I am connecting to the database as, in both SSMS and CR, has full administrative access/capabilities against all schemas in the database in question
3. Points 1 and 2 would suggest that this is not a security related issue
4. I am connecting to the database in CR through an ODBC connection created on my system through ODBC Data Source Administration (32-bit) - as a System DSN
5. The ODBC Data Source uses the same administrative account being used directly in CR and SSMS

Thank you in advance for your help. Please let me know if there is any additional information that I can provide to help solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue few years back, and as per my experience it has nothing to do with database and it is within the crystal reports where a registry value is set to minimum value which will restrict the display of schemas or tables

Check below link which will show you the path to change registry.

[forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1004707](http://forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1004707)

I would suggest you to first take back up of the original data and then change the value

Comment: this link is dead, anyway someone could provide the info?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

On the menu bar, select File –> Options.
Click the “Database” tab.
Uncheck the “Stored Procedures” option.

[Someone on another forum said that worked but he did not know why.](https://seankilleen.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/fix-crystal-reports-2008-database-explorer-doesnt-show-all-schemas-field-notes/)

Comment: This kind of worked. It ended up removing the dbo and sys schemas, and two of the missing schemas appeared in their place, however not all of the missing schemas came in.

Comment: Sounds like another Crystal bug... :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Crystal under File-->Options-->Database where one can set owner like %. Perhaps your Crystal install has an old setting limiting your visible schemas?

[image: Filtering DB objects in Crystal]

Comment: Thanks @Cyndi1976, I checked that setting in my version of Crystal Reports. The Owner box was empty, I tried updating to % with no luck before changing it back to empty.

Comment: Was a bit of a long shot since someone would have had to add that to the Crystal instance at some point.

Comment: Another possibility is permissions wackiness.  This anecdote has nothing to do with schemas but illustrates how permissions can misbehave: I have seen columns with certain datatypes disappear in the past from users' Crystal field explorer when their DB user was not dbo.  Their db user would have sufficient permission to read the column but the columns were still not there.  Granting their user View Definition fixed it and the columns appeared. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdc29844-278f-4e52-bcbf-947d6510a8eb/dbdatareader-cant-see-userdefined-types

Answer (score 0):

For any one in 2022 who is facing this problem. Check the following:

1. Open odbc, 32 bits odbc.
2. Select your datasource and click configure
3. Click details
4. Select Metadata tab
5. Uncheck Disable Schema support and click Ok.

Solved, this is tested and working